# tracing javascript function flow

Tags: javascript, performance-testing

I'm debugging and optimizing a page and have found that the js profiler in firebug is great, the only problem is that I've found the problem, however it's a call from the ajax class in my jQuery file, i'm wondering how I would backtrace it into my code. I'm super new to debugging/optimizing performance, so I'm sorry if this is an easy answer.

thanks,
Brodie

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can put `console.trace()` statement into your function code and it will give you the trace of function calls in firebug

**Reference:**

http://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Console_API